# Mysql Update based on existence in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out how to mass update a mysql table based on if a value exists in a  column in another table.

e.g. pseudo code:

```
if Table1.`col`=Table2.`col` then
  Update Table1.`status`=1
```

or

```
if table2.`col` exists in table1.`col`
  Update Table1.`status`=1
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: In both conditions you set status = 1: so you don't need a condition. Can you be more precise please? Are they the same condition?

Answer (score 9):

Try this one -

```
UPDATE table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.col = t2.col
SET t1.status = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Table 1

```
col  | status 
-------------

jaga |   0

kala |   0
```

Table 2

```
col   | status 
--------------

jaga  |   1

latha |   0
```

If Table1.`col`=Table2.`col` // So this point is fullfill jaga record.
then Update Table1.`status`=1 // So Table 1 jaga row status want to Update in 1.

Is I am Correct?.

Then Try

```
UPDATE Table1 AS t1, Table2 AS t2 SET t1.col = 1 WHERE t1.col  = t2.col
```

Happy Codings,

Comment: may be this not help to The OP

Comment: I ran this and it appears to work well. I found the syntax easier to read.

Answer (score -1):

```
update t_checkout A
INNER JOIN t_target B on A.Media_ID = B.Media_ID
set A.status = 'R'
where A.Media_ID = 45
and exists (select * from t_target where B.Media_ID = 45 and status = 'R');
```

The 45 is hard coded here, but the value actually comes from a php parameter.